# KafkaListner initialoffset consume messages already acknowledged?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have 465264 records in kafka but i already consume all messages and also acknowledged but when i tried to start consuming with initial offset then after acknowledge it consume again and again same message. Following is my code:

```
@KafkaListener(
    id = "${kafka.buyers.product-sales-pricing.id}",
    groupId = "${kafka.buyers.group-id}",
    concurrency = "${kafka.buyers.concurrency}",
    topicPartitions = { @TopicPartition( topic = "${kafka.buyers.product-sales-pricing.topic}", partitionOffsets = @PartitionOffset( partition = "0", initialOffset = "465260" ) ) }
)
public void listen( List<String> messages, Acknowledgment ack ){}
```

Yml configuration:

```
spring:
    kafka:
      bootstrapServers: kafka.moglilabs.com:29092
      consumer:
        enable-auto-commit: false
        autoOffsetReset: earliest
        keyDeserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        valueDeserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer #spring message converter will take care of deserialization
        max-poll-records: 1000
```

Comment: `autoOffsetReset: earliest` -> every time you start your application it will read the data from the the beginning again

Comment: No. The `autoOffsetReset` should not apply at every start of the app. It should only apply if the broker does not know the offset of this consumer-group.

Comment: @Paizo I don't think so because if i run my project without initialOffset, everything work fine for all offset but i want consuming messages from some specific offset.

Comment: @ankit did you find a solution? I am running into the same problem